# How to inititialize a vector of pairs inside a structure?

Tags: c++

I need to manually add items to vector "items" in the following code, but I get an error "emplace_back': function does not take 5 arguments" - how do I make it work?

```
    enum class ITM {
        ...
    };

    enum class RES {
        res1,
        res2
    };

    typedef std::vector<std::pair<RES,int>> ingredient_list;

    struct _item {
        ITM name;
        double buy, sell, craft;
        ingredient_list ingr;
    };

    std::vector<_item> items;

    items.emplace_back(ITM::lm54, 0, 0, 0, { {RES::res1, 50}, {RES::res2, 70} });
```

Comment: Note: while `struct _item` is valid, `struct _Item` would be using a reserved identifier (identifier starting with underscore followed by upper case letter). I would avoid leading underscores in identifiers if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Type `_item` does not have a constructor with five arguments, but the move constructor can be used.

```
items.emplace_back(_item{ ..., ..., ..., ..., ... });
```

`emplace_back()` tries to find a constructor of `_item` that accepts the same arguments in order to *forward* them in a call to this constructor.
The move constructor exists implicitly (except if disabled explicitly or by some of the data members) so providing a temporary `_item` as argument to `emplace_back()` makes a good candidate to forward it to the move constructor that will be used for in-place construction inside the vector.

Comment: thank you! why is it necessary to add _item? c++ should understand what it is from definition of items vector?

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't your code works? Because of two things.

`emplace_back` deducts arguments and you've passed initializater lists (`{}` without any type in front). Initializer lists don't work well with template deduction (in fact they don't work at all, for example:

```
template <typename F> void foo(F &&f)
{
    std::vector<int> q = f;
}        
int main()
{
    foo({ 1 });
}
```

produces dreaded:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:12:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
  foo({ 1 });
           ^
prog.cpp:5:28: note: candidate: template<class F> void foo(F&&)
 template <typename F> void foo(F &&f)
                            ^~~
prog.cpp:5:28: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:12:11: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘F’
  foo({ 1 });
           ^
```

To amend this you need to add type:

```
items.emplace_back(ITM::lm54, 0, 0, 0, ingredient_list{ {RES::res1, 50}, {RES::res2, 70} });
```

Second this is that your `items_` type is POD (plain old data - no constructors and few other things). Compiler allows you to initialize POD types using constructor syntax (`_item(values)`), but this doesn't fly with `vector` (and other containers), as those use inside something like this:

```
::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

which ignores POD thing. So you either need to prepend arguments with type name (thus creating your object and forcing compiler to use move constructor) or you've to define the constructor in your class (thus sidestepping whole POD thing issue).

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because you need a constructor for `_item` that takes all 5 arguments, and it appears that you don't have one.

Fortunately, as of C++11, you can use [list_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
items.push_back({ITM::lm54, 0, 0, 0, { {RES::res1, 50}, {RES::res2, 70} }});
```

You simply put the information you need to initialize the item between curly braces. This should create an `_item` object, which is then pushed into the container.

Comment: `push_back()` expects a (reference on) `T` so the compiler knows that the brace initialisation aims at creating a `T`. On the other hand, `emplace_back()` expects a variable number of forwarding references (on anything); the fact that these forwarding references will be used to initialise a `T` is only known in the definition, but does not appear in the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
std::vector<_item> items{
    { ITM::Foo, 1., 2., 3., { { RES::res1, 1 } } },
    { ITM::Bar, 4., 5., 6., { { RES::res1, 2 }, { RES::res2, 3 } } }
};
```

Comment: Where is `emplace_back()`? ;^)

Comment: @prog-fh Nowhere. The title of the question asked about how to initialize, so I provided an example using initialization.